# Azure/Databricks - Best way to ingest data?

Tags: azure, databricks

I'm new to Azure & Databricks. I've been watching training videos and do have cloud experience with AWS. However I'm on a time crunch so help would be appreciated. I have multiple data sources I need live data ingest (via API calls/database connection) into azure and run transformations/ML in Databricks. I will likely need to output the cleaned dataframe(s) into a DW or sql database that will have a BI connection. If someone with experience in Azure Databricks can help with recommending which products I need, that would be terrific. Note this is not 'big data' (Only 100,000 rows max) but will need a compute capacity to run ML (NLP) quickly.

```
1. ELT/ETL - Should I go Datafactory -> Databricks. Or maybe Kafka -> blob storage -> Databricks?
2. Recommended worker type size for live data processing / NLP application?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is begining of the project, the simplest way is just to write notebooks in Databricks and connect to source and Load data to dbfs storage than process that data again in Databricks (ML etc).

If it is small dataset just take simplest 1 worker + driver for that.

In future you can always upgrade worker type and set to run notebooks jobs via Data Factory.

Comment: So you're saying no need to have independent storage? Can I still achieve real time processing if my entire workload was on databricks? I thought in order to achieve this... I would also need a storage solution that is collecting data real time from my sources and pushing them to databricks

Comment: databricks have built-in streaming but everything depends what exactly data sources are. Maybe Azure data factory can be interesting for you as well.

Comment: Hubert thanks for the recommendations! One question... would I need storage (Azure Storage) in between Data Factory and Databricks? If Data Factory is capable of storing and updating raw data, I imagine my use case for real time (near real time processing) would be better off if I didn't have an intermediary storage step

Comment: some storage is always needed :-) (and Azure blob or delta lake can be accessed from both anyway)  but yes is the best is to use stream everywhere when possible (but from my experience I want to use stream but than can not as there is no one).

Answer (score 0):

Always ELT approach is recommended One rather than ETL in modern data handling. Data should be landed in datalake before transforming into business use case. This is always recommended pattern any distributed systems based tools..in You can refer [link](https://databricks.com/session_eu20/speeding-time-to-insight-with-a-modern-elt-approach)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Technically the two methods I'm considering are ELT based

Comment: that is nice. by the way , what kind of databricks environment yours - either azure or aws databricks ?

Comment: Azure. I'm considering Data Factory to extract my on-prem data and house it in blob storage that would be connected to databricks. Only thing I need more clarification on is real time data processing ie. will this model work and are there any options/configurations I need to change to enable real time streaming